# Count number of lines per date in pivot table

Tags: excel, google-sheets, pivot-table

I'm freshening up on creating pivot tables and am a little stuck.

**I am using Google Sheets.**

I have data that has columns that include "Date" and "Comments".

I create a pivot table doing the following:

Add rows:
"Date" and "Comments"

Add filter:
I just select keywords in the comments that I'm searching for (ie. all comments with the word "turtle" in them).

This is where I'm having issues...
I want to have a third column that sums up the number of comments that are showing (after the filter has been applied) for each date.

Any tips?

FYI, if you're having trouble picturing the pivot table, it looks like this:

```
Date       Comments          (I want a 3rd column to be "# of instances per date")
1/1/18     Possible Turtle
           Another Turtle
Total                            2
1/2/18     Possible Turtle
           Another Turtle
           Ninja Turtle
Total                            3
```

My goal is to create a chart that shows total number of comments that have the keyword (ie. "Turtle"), per date.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I actually just figured this out.

I just checked the box **"Show Totals"** on the **COMMENTS** row and then added a **VALUE** (I selected **COMMENTS** for my value).

I then said to **Summarize by COUNTUNIQUE**.

This give me a table that looks just like what I was trying to get, except I have a **1** at the end of each line.

```
Date       Comments          COUNTUNIQUE
1/1/18     Possible Turtle       1
           Another Turtle        1
Total                            2
1/2/18     Possible Turtle       1
           Another Turtle        1
           Ninja Turtle          1
Total                            3
```

That should work! Hope this helps someone else having the same problem!